# Differential equation for trivial RL series circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, coil

I would like to obtain differential equation describing behaviour of this circuit. I'm really new to this and not quite sure how to begin. We can consider situation of knowing values of all parameters of circuit: *U (voltage)*, *R (resistance)*, *L (inductance)* and *iL (current)*.

[image]

I assume final equation should include all of the variables, so for given values it gives us idea of how the circuit behaves. I found this equation which might possibly fulfill those assumptions:

[image]

How should I proceed in case this formula is correct?

Comment: The formula is correct. So, what exactly do you mean, "how do I proceed"? Other than solving the equation, I mean? You can find i as a function of V, which will give you the voltage across R, for instance. So specify V, solve the equation, and see what you get.

Comment: @John Smith: How you should proceed depends on where you want to go. What is your goal? If your goal really just was "to obtain differential equation describing behaviour of this circuit" then you are done and don't have to proceed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the voltage is applied via a switch in series (not shown), the solution for the current will be i(t)=V/R(1-exp[(-R/L)t].  V is your U in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to *solve* the differential equation. To do this mathematically yourself you would be on the wrong site. For engineering purposes you could use a CAS. You might use [wxMaxima](http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/) to do the following:

Create a signal by summing some sines:

```
s(t) := sum((1/(2*n-1))*sin(2*%pi*(2*n-1)*f*t),n,1,3);
```

Build the equation:

```
eq: s(t) = R*i + L*'diff(i,t,1);
```

Use the built-in ODE solver (ode2) to calculate the solutions for the equation:

```
sols: ode2(eq,i,t);
```

The result (sols) describes all solutions of the equation, while for a specific case one specific solution is needed. Function ic1() sets boundary conditions that define a single solution. (here t=0 and i=0)

```
sol: ic1(sols,t=0,i=0);
```

Build a function out of the solution:

```
i(t) := ev(rhs(sol));
```

Set up some component values:

```
filter1: [
    R=10,
    L=50e-3
];
```

And plot the result for 50Hz:

```
wxplot2d([s(t),i(t)],[t,0,0.1]), f=50, filter1;
```

[image: RL filter]

Comment: Wha does "CAS" stand for?

Answer (score 0):

The equation you have found is the answer to your question.

How to get it from the circuit? Just apply KVL to the only loop you have in your circuit.

I'm assuming U is a step voltage.

The voltage of an inductor is given by

$$v_l = \frac{di}{dt}$$

So that leaves us with the complete KVL:

$$U = Ri + L\frac{di}{dt}$$

this equation has nice solution in the form of:

$$i(t) = A e^{(-kt)} + B$$

if you apply the initial and final conditions to your circuit you'll find that:

$$i(t) = \frac{U}{R}(1- e^{(-\frac{Rt}{L})})$$.

EDIT:
I'm not sure if you're asking how to proceed to solve the differential equation or how to proceed in general. There are general methods to solve circuits that can be applied sistematically using matrices, however in circuits as simple as this one, they're definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one current -- *I* -- but there are multiple voltages and voltage drops around the circuit -- *V<sub>R</sub>*, *V<sub>L</sub>* and *U*.

We know how the current through the inductor changes:

$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{V_L}{L}$$
And from Ohm's law:
$$V_R = IR$$
And because it's a circuit the source voltage equals the total voltage drop:
$$U = V_L+V_R$$

Solving for the derivative of current in terms of *U* is easy:

$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{U-V_R}{L} = \frac{U-IR}{L}$$